# MYSQL - Compare rows in same table and show distinct

Tags: mysql

I want to compare rows in the same table and show what has changed from last days data

For Eg: if my Metrics table is as below

```
  id  |   Server  |   Component   | Status          | Date
------+----------+-------------------------------------------
  1   |   Node1   |   Service     | Compliant       | 10-1-2018
  2   |   Node1   |   IP          | Compliant       | 10-1-2018
  3   |   Node2   |   Service     | Non-Compliant   | 10-1-2018
  4   |   Node2   |   IP          | Compliant       | 10-1-2018
  5   |   Node1   |   Service     | Compliant       | 09-1-2018
  6   |   Node1   |   IP          | Compliant       | 09-1-2018
  7   |   Node2   |   Service     | Compliant       | 09-1-2018 
  8   |   Node2   |   IP          | Compliant       | 09-1-2018
```

The result I want is as below because the Node 2 service compliance state has changed (to Non-Compliant) compared with the last day state

```
Node2   |   Service     | Non-Compliant  | 09-1-2018
```

What I want is basically to track compliance status change for a node when compared with last day data

Thanks

Comment: Are you using MySQL/MariaDB or SQL Server (TSQL) ? Please dont spam tag all the RDBMS

Comment: I am using Mysql, i am new to databases and learning. I thought SQL logic is more or less same with all RDBMS and thought someone could help me learn. Thanks

Comment: You have multiple entries with different Status values on same date. This is conflicting with your defined logic.

Comment: Each RDBMS uses its own version of SQL flavour. So it is best to specify the exact RDBMS you are using.

Comment: Ok, i have edited to reflect MySQL. Thanks

Comment: Note that `Node2   |  Service` is both Compliant and Non compliant on the same date. It does not go well with your defined logic.

Comment: Yes, different status values. Data is collected from the same node and uploaded to the database. If the parameter is changed from the default, it will flag is non-compliant, whereas the rest of the details will not change apart from date. What I am trying to achieve is a logic, which can compare data uploaded from the same node in the last two days and show if something has changed from compliant to non-compliant. The dates are different.  The table will keep getting uploaded with similar data from 100+ nodes every day. Thanks

Comment: Sample table value is Node 2, service compliant on 8th and became non-compliant on 10.

Comment: It also became compliant on 10th. So, it defies your 2 days logic. I think you mean that *any change* occurred on another day is to be considered. If that is so, you should rephrase the problem statement a bit more and make it unambiguous. Btw most likely this is the reason of 2 negative votes on your question (not mine votes though!)

Comment: I have updated my question. Sorry, I am new to this forum and databases. Edited to make my question more understandable. Thanks for pointing my mistake.

Comment: Also, the components are different, service & ip. Service state has changed to non-compliant, whereas the  IP state is still compliant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1b0c46/1

```
SELECT t_next.*
FROM t1 t_prev
JOIN t1 t_next
ON t_next.server = t_prev.server
   AND t_next.component = t_prev.component
   AND t_next.date = t_prev.date + INTERVAL 1 DAY
   AND t_next.status != t_prev.status
WHERE t_prev.date = '2018-01-09'
```

Comment: Thanks Alex. That worked perfectly. Actually my data is more complex than the example i have given. I have learned from your approach and modified to my need as belowSELECT t_next.Server,t_next.`Compliance-Status`
FROM cd t_prev
JOIN cd t_next
ON t_next.`Server` = t_prev.`Server`
   AND t_next.`System-Parameter` = t_prev.`System-Parameter`
   AND t_next.`Compliance-Status` != t_prev.`Compliance-Status`
   AND date(t_next.`TOI`) = date(t_prev.`TOI`) + INTERVAL 7 day
WHERE t_next.`Compliance-Status` = 'Non-Compliant'

Comment: Thanks, Alex. That worked perfectly. Actually, my data is more complex than the example I have given. I learned from your approach and modified as below to match my requirement.

Comment: SELECT t_next.Server,t_next.`Status`,t_next.'DOR'
FROM Table t_prev
JOIN Table t_next
ON t_next.`Server` = t_prev.`Server`
   AND t_next.`System-Parameter` = t_prev.`System-Parameter`
   AND t_next.`Status` != t_prev.`Status`
   AND date(t_next.`TOI`) = date(t_prev.`TOI`) + INTERVAL 7 day
WHERE t_next.`Status` = 'Non-Compliant'